# Opening a new window from multiple combo boxes

Tags: javascript, combobox

I have 3 combo boxes named MCC1, MCC2, and MCC3. I have an onChange function assigned to them with javascript that collects the index value selected and then opens a new window to a desired web page.

```
var x=document.form.MCC.options[document.form.MCC.selectedIndex].value;

window.open('http://server/page='+x+'&tab=0','mywindow','width=400,height=200')
```

I want to use the same function for all 3 combo boxes, but the function needs to know which combo box name value the onchange is coming from. Right now it only reads the last value,if I use multiple var's. I've tried tackling this several ways with an array, multiple var's, and even creating a var for the name value. I'm fairly new to js and unsure what is the best way to tackle this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this : http://jsfiddle.net/DUMBH/

```
function call(op) {
alert(op.name) //name of combobox
alert(op.value); // selected value
var x = op.value;

window.open('http://server/page=' + x + '&tab=0', 'mywindow', 'width=400,height=200')
}​
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, Thank You! Also, Thanks for showing me jsfiddle, (now bookmarked in my toolbox).

Answer (score 0):

You can try below way

JS:

```
function OpenWindow(target){
var x=$(target).val();
window.open('http://server/page='+x+'&tab=0','mywindow','width=400,height=200')
}
```

HTML:

```
<select onchange="penWindow(this)" name="MCC1">...</select>
<select onchange="penWindow(this)" name="MCC2">...</select>
<select onchange="penWindow(this)" name="MCC3">...</select>
```